# Open form in an application(c# windows app) from another application (outlook plug-in)f

Tags: c#

Let me put the Scenario for the requirement ...

1.Our windows application is running and say suppose it has forms like Form1,Form2....
2.From Outlook-Plugin (custom addin) for some particular action we want to open Form1 in already running windows application ......

As we know from System. Diagonistics we can know the active processes for a system . With this I was able to locate process for running windows application but not sure how to open new form in that application ....Help Appreciable , Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a button in your main form that opens `Form1` and simulate a click on it with WinAPI.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindowExW",  SetLastError=true,
    CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx( IntPtr Ph,IntPtr Ch,
    IntPtr Ph1,
    String lpWindowName);

System.IntPtr hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero,"Form1");
    System.IntPtr ptrChild = GetWindow(this.Handle, GW_CHILD) ;
    while(!ptrChild.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        if(ptrChild == FindWindowEx(hwnd,IntPtr.Zero,IntPtr.Zero,"button2"))
        {
            SendMessage(ptrChild, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, IntPtr.Zero); 
            SendMessage(ptrChild, WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, IntPtr.Zero); 
            SendMessage(ptrChild, BM_SETSTATE,1 , IntPtr.Zero);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            ptrChild = GetWindow(ptrChild, GW_HWNDNEXT) ;
        }
    }
```

Information about `FindWindowEx` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx